# ruby192: specific method calling

Tags: ruby

```
module B
  def stub
    extend()
  end

  def extend
    puts "B:extend"
  end
end

class A
  include B
  def extend
    puts "A:extend"
  end
end

a = A.new

a.stub 
# output: A:extend
# would like to have: B:extend
```

The question is:
How to make `a.stub` call `extend` method from module `B` without modifying `B`'s code and without renaming `A`'s method `extend`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`include B` adds `B`'s methods to `A` so your method definition is overwriting `B`'s implementation.

You could use the `alias` method to save a reference to `B`'s method and implement your own `stub` method in `A`:

```
class A
  include B
  alias :b_extend :extend

  def stub
    b_extend
  end

  def extend
    puts "A:extend"
  end
end

A.new.stub
# B:extend
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a monkey patch could solve this.

```
module B
  alias original_stub stub
  alias b_extend extend
  def stub
    b_extend
  end
end
```

But if your project does have many calls to original stub... each call should be modified.

Comment: Just to be clear, that `stub` is from RSpec gem, so i've asked about the solution with `B`'s code not being modified.

Answer (score 1):

```
def a.extend
  self.class.ancestors[1].instance_method(:extend).bind(self).call
end
```

Answer (score 1):

My just another try.

```
A.class_eval do
 if self.include? B
   def extend
     super
   end
  end
end

A.new.stub
#=> B:extend
```

Correct me if this is a wrong approach.